# Create 1 bit raster with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal

Is it possible to reduce a raster to hold just 1 or 0 values with gdal? I find no data formats less than "Byte" in the documention

Answer (score 3):

GeoTIFF with NBITS=1 is binary even the datatype is Byte https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html. I do not know the internal structure of such TIFF but together with the [CCITT Group 4 compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_4_compression) that is designed long time ago for fax machines it yields very small file size.

Usage:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co NBITS=1 -co compress=CCITTFAX4 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: I recommend NOT blindly using that compression. For a random 1 bit noise image I made it did increase the file size by double compared to just using `NBITS=1` alone.

Comment: Add `-ot Byte` to avoid errors: `NBITS is not supported for data type Int32` and `Fax3SetupState:Bits/sample must be 1 for Group 3/4 encoding/decoding`